# How to call a specific function from JS file to feature file in karate

Tags: karate, intuit-partner-platform

My JS file(functions.js) is:

```
function one(a1){
    return (a1 + "one")
}
function two(a2){
    return (a1 + "two")
}
```

I wish to call a specific function of the JS file with specified argument (ball) in the feature file something like this:

```
* def functionOneResponse = call read('functions.js') {one("ball")}
* print functionOneResponse
```

The response is expected to be "ball one". Is there any way to do this?